# Printing .stl file using ObJetPro 3D Printer

Tags: software, scaling

I am trying to 3D print some shells for a project, and would like them to be about 5 cm long.

I created the shells in Blender and converted them to `.stl` files which the printer requires, but it tries to print them as 0.02 mm long. I am not printing them myself, so I have to rescale the files without access to the actual printer. I have tried scaling the object both in Blender, and when exporting them to `.stl` files, but can't figure out how to tell what size the printer will interpret the shells as.

Is there a way to make sure I have the objects scaled properly before printing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way is to install slicer on your pc and open the .stl file.
Most slicers will tell you the size of an object and there is an option to rescale resize.

Using `Slic3r` you will have object details in the corner
[image]

Using CURA you will have a detailed view in scale mode 
[image]

Also you can use online services [CLICK](https://www.viewstl.com)
[image: an online service stl viewer]

Comment: Very good answer that shows various options, an option I usually take (if I also want to edit the model file) is to load the STL is Fusion360 / FreeCAD (or other 3D modeling application that is available) and scale and adapt the model there. When loading STL files (e.g. from thingiverse.com) I always need to scale down by a factor of 10.

Comment: @0scar - thanks for good wards. The editing topic was skipped as OP has already tool to create an object.